# Java Multiple threads for just 2 computers, how to do it in main

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server

I'm trying to get at least two computers to connect to my server, how would i start a second thread?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // Create the server which waits for a client to request a connection.


while(true){
    FileSharedServer server = new FileSharedServer();
    Thread thread = new Thread(server);
    thread.start();
}
   }
```

this refuses my connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait on serverSocket.accept() method on incoming connections in your server, and after receiving one start a thread to serve it, but the server socket stay the same, you just do waiting for next connection in a loop.

```
while (true) {
    Socket connection = serverSocket.accept();
    new Therad() {
         public void run() {
              serveConnection(connection);
         }
    }.start();
}
```